No overload matches this call error in React Native
Issue
The following code throws an error. The code is a minimal executable code to reproduce the error of the original one.
import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const MyButton = () => {
  return (
    <Button
      title="Click me"
      style={styles.button}
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#0f0',
    color: '#fff',
    padding: 10,
  },
});

The error:
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ButtonProps): Button', gave the following error.
    Type '{ title: string; style: { backgroundColor: string; color: string; padding: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button> & Readonly<ButtonProps>'.
      Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button> & Readonly<ButtonProps>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ButtonProps, context: any): Button', gave the following error.
    Type '{ title: string; style: { backgroundColor: string; color: string; padding: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button> & Readonly<ButtonProps>'.
      Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button> & Readonly<ButtonProps>'.ts(2769)

As a result, the react native webpage is empty.
Environment

Windows 11
npm 10.8.2

What I did so far
I checked the following pages in vain.

reactjs - React + TypeScript error: No overload matches this call - Stack Overflow
typescript - Why is there a "No overload matches this call" error when passing a reactive prop? - Stack Overflow
reactjs - how to solve No overload matches this call error typescript - Stack Overflow

What should I do to solve this?


Property 'style' does not exist…

The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. The Button component from React Native does not have a style prop.
“No overload matches this call” means you’re passing a property or combination of properties that can’t exist, based on the component’s typing.
